# Automatic english spell-checking in a CI/CD pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, markdown, spell-checking

I am looking for a tool to spell-check English markdown documents in a pipeline.

Having seen and heard about the Hunspell project, I am not sure if that is the right tool to use - however looking online I might not use the right search terms or my approach is wrong as I do not find many results at all.

Anyone who has any advice of the direction to go?

Answer (score 4):

Answering myself: this is a task for which the [codespell](https://github.com/codespell-project/codespell) CLI tool can be used.

Comment: Codespell only checks for "common misspellings" which is good for regular code to keep false positives low. For markdown, html and such which are intended to host mainly non programming language this might not be the ideal tool, I'd rather have a checker that strips all markup and sends the raw text though a regular spell checker. If anyone knows about such a tool that would be a much better answer here!

Comment: Ok, hunspell is the tool I was looking for, thanks for providing this in your question! My use case is html, I have no experience spell-checking markdown unfortunately.